# Jquery Ajax not showing success or error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "search.aspx/gdata",
   data: '{jobid: "test"}',
   dataType: "json",
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   cache: false,
   async: false,
   success: function(response) {
   alert(response.d);
},
   failure: function(response) {
   alert(response.d);
   }
});
```

This my script. If I put top 20 records in the sql query in the code behind page, then it gets the data. But if I put top 21 records, then it wont work.

What I mean is, it will retrieve certain number of records or less but not above.

Is it because of the number of records? or the size of the string data? or what else?

Please help. Its killing my brains.

Comment: Read the docs...there is no `failure` settings option....change it to `error` and `response` will not have a property `d` in that method as would in success

Comment: What do you mean by "then it wont work." ? Is it returning error. ? May be there is exception in Backend when you pass 21.

Answer (score 0):

based on the Ajax doc there's no failure and i think this is why your request is not giving back anything. you should check the doc [Ajax Doc](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)
there is success, error, fail, done, complete ...

Comment: Thank you for quick response sir. 

I am still stumped why I am not getting alert(response.d). I will get the alert if he records are 20, but no alert if records are 21 or more. Please help.,

Comment: maybe it's a cache problem, as you set it to false and the request needs more cache then it has and it's causing an error

Comment: I have put Cache= true and then tried removing the cache option from the script. But still it is the same problem

Comment: maybe there is a server problem, check your server logs and the response that your getting back from the server

Comment: No. its not server problem. I debugged the script and its fine, however, the problem is it shows records till 20, but not if records are 21